# ReadFile always returns false. GetLastError reoprts ERROR_IO_PENDING. Waitforsingleobject passes

Tags: c++, winapi, overlapped-io, com-port

What I am trying to do is to get frames of data from a COM port. The data frames are 258 bytes each, and are constantly coming in at a rate of about 8.5 per second.

I need to receive the data frames and then I will do some other processing on them, but for now I am trying to just print them out to the console. Each data frame starts with `'/'` and ends with `'?'`.

Here is the code I wrote (yes I'm a noob at this):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>

#include "windows.h"
#pragma comment (lib, "OneCore.lib")

int main()
{
    int portnum = 0;

    ULONG ptNums[300];
    ULONG some = 300;
    ULONG ptsFound[20];
    LPCSTR fName = "COM4";

    ULONG status = GetCommPorts(ptNums, 100, ptsFound);
    if (status == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "ports found:" << ptsFound[0] << "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < ptsFound[0]; i++) {
            portnum = ptNums[i];
            std::cout << "COM" << portnum << "\n";
        }
    }

    HANDLE port = CreateFileA(fName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0);
    if (port == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cout << "unable to open port\n";

    }

    DCB dcb;
    dcb = { 0 };
    //this is the default, use 8N1
    dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);
    dcb.fBinary = TRUE;
    dcb.BaudRate = 250000;
    dcb.fParity = FALSE;
    dcb.ByteSize = 8;
    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;

    DWORD eventMask;

    SetCommState(port, &dcb);
    SetCommMask(port,EV_TXEMPTY|EV_RXCHAR);

    bool exitloop = false;
    char arduBuf[258];

    OVERLAPPED ov;
    ov.Offset = 0;
    ov.OffsetHigh = 0;
    ov.hEvent = CreateEvent(0, TRUE, 0, 0);
    SetupComm(port, 300, 300);

    while (!exitloop) {
        
        GetCommMask(port, &eventMask);
        BOOL dataRet = WaitCommEvent(port, &eventMask, &ov);
        DWORD dwait = WaitForSingleObject(ov.hEvent, INFINITE);
        
        if (eventMask & EV_TXEMPTY) {
            std::cout << "all data was sent\n";
            exitloop = true;
        }

        if (dwait == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
            GetCommMask(port, &eventMask);
            std::cout << "some random stuff was received\n";

            BOOL status = ReadFile(port, arduBuf, sizeof(arduBuf), NULL, &ov);
            std::cout << "status:" << status << "\nerror is:" << GetLastError() << "\n";
            PurgeComm(port, PURGE_RXCLEAR);
            if (status) {
                std::cout << arduBuf << "\n";
            }
            ResetEvent(ov.hEvent);
            //exitloop = true;
        }

        if (dwait == WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
            std::cout << "timeout\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The code compiles and runs, and `WaitForSingleObject()` returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, but the status is always 0 and `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_IO_PENDING`. If I print out the data buffer regardless, then I can see my data, but its on a few jumbled lines and very inconsistent:

[image: screenshot]

I think this is because although `EV_RXCHAR` is satisfied, `EV_TXEMPTY` never is. If I set the mask to `EV_TXEMPTY` only, then the code hangs at `WaitForSingleObject()`. I think this is because before the data gets read, there is new data already filling the input buffer.

My questions:

- There is obviously something wrong here. Can someone point it out?
- I am not sure if stuffing the reading into a `while` loop is a good idea. I know I should stuff it into a thread that terminates once a read has failed or was successful, but is the `while` loop actually causing problems?
- I get a warning on the `WaitForSingleObject()` line that `ov.hEvent` could be 0. Why is this so, and can it also be an issue?
- When do I need to reset the event?

As you can tell, I am new to COM port I/O. I've spent over a day on this and decided it was time to ask someone that knows what they are doing.

Comment: You are asking for an asynchronous overlapped I/O. The function is telling you that it has started, and will complete asynchronously. That's what `ERROR_IO_PENDING` means. From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile): "Note  The `GetLastError` code `ERROR_IO_PENDING` is not a failure; it designates the read operation is pending completion asynchronously. For more information, see Remarks."

Comment: COM port examples show this `OVERLAPPED` thing because meanwhile you are expecting to receive something, you may want to be able to send stuff at arbitrary times. However here that doesn't seem to be the case and you could try the entire thing in the classic synchronous, non-overlapped way. So don't pass the flag, don't use the structure, and for `ReadFile` directly, and yes, it will be a filthy blocking operation, but that's what you actually want.

Comment: And if you want the overlapped thing, after facing `ERROR_IO_PENDING`, you would need `GetOverlappedResult()` to get an update, see [remark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-waitcommevent#remarks)

Comment: @tevemadar Well damn, I just watered it down to just the readline and it works the way I want it to. Thanks!

Comment: *When do I need to reset the event?* - you not need `ResetEvent(ov.hEvent);` at all. system do this by self. after you got `ERROR_IO_PENDING` read yet not completed and data can be not in `arduBuf`, so need wait first I/O complete, before use `arduBuf`. reading into a while loop is not a good idea, but possible implementation. *warning on the WaitForSingleObject()* - is compiler bug

Comment: @RbMm The warning is valid. It's warning you that you didn't check whether `CreateEvent` succeeded. If it failed, then you're waiting on nullptr, which is not allowed, and the program goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: If someone wants to play LEGO with this overlapped thing, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832718/serial-port-reading-in-c-using-winapi-functions-waitcommevent-fails may be interesting to check out for bricks.

Answer (score 0):

As [@tevemadar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7916438/tevemadar) said, `ERROR_IO_PENDING` is not a failure; it designates the read operation is pending completion asynchronously.

*If the overlapped operation cannot be completed immediately, the function returns FALSE and the `GetLastError` function returns `ERROR_IO_PENDING`, indicating that the operation is executing in the background. When this happens, the system sets the hEvent member of the `OVERLAPPED` structure to the not-signaled state before `WaitCommEvent` returns, and then it sets it to the signaled state when one of the specified events or an error occurs.*

Using the `GetOverlappedResult` function to determine the results of the `WaitCommEvent` operation can get some updates.